# How to use initialize in CakePHP 2.X

Tags: cakephp

I'm migrating a Cake 1.3 App to an 2.X app. It is mostly working well but I don't understand how I can rewrite this code for Cake 2.

```
    public function initialize(&$controller) {
        $this->Controller =& $controller;
    }
```

The error warning is:
*Cannot assign by reference to overloaded object*

Comment: Where is this function call in your existing CakePHP application?

Comment: Have you read the Migration guide? At CakePHP 2 there were some chages with the initialize component: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html#components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you really should read the migration guide at
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html

```
public function initialize(Controller $controller) {
    $this->Controller = $controller;
}
```

you can try to run my Upgrade shell. it should fix most of those itself:
https://github.com/dereuromark/upgrade

```
cake Upgrade.Correct reference
```

should do the trick

see https://github.com/dereuromark/upgrade/blob/master/Console/Command/CorrectShell.php#L733